What's the equivalent "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu" option in autoinstallation yaml file?
I don't want to create a lot of partitions in yaml file, I would like just to insert default configs and didn't find anything explaining how can I do that, does anyone know how to apply "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu" in yaml autoinstall file?

If you know the disk (e.g. /dev/sda) then a simple autoinstall snippet could be as follows.
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  early-commands:
    - wipefs -a /dev/sda
  storage:
    layout:
      name: lvm

